# Answers in Comments

Tags: discussion, answered-questions

When looking for unanswered questions, if we see one that has been answered but just in the comments, what should we do? I came across one where someone answered their question in the comments, and the poster then replied and said "thanks, that works". So I naturally went in and wrote the answer, to mark it as such. Should I mark my post as a duplicate, or something else? I was just a bit unclear on that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a [look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157889/is-posting-someones-comment-as-an-answer-okay/256732#256732) first.

**Disclaimer**: I am not a moderator; I do not set policies, so this is just a personal opinion. (And a very obvious one)  **;-)**

As a new user it's always difficult: The first 50 points of reputation are hardest to get.  But there are tons of things you can do to get more rep:

- Ask good questions
- Edit spelling/grammar/formatting/tags (all of them: don't just add *irrelevant* tags!) to improve the quality of the existing questions/answers.
- Flag spam/inappropriate language/...
- Give good answers

*Having said all that:* You can still leave a comment [@Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) below [the specific question you're talking about](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623386/ubuntu-14-04-lts-dual-boot-problem-with-windows-7) and ask him personally if he minds...

Comment: I am unable at this time to leave comments, but I will look at ading the community wiki. Thank you for the guidance, I want to be be fair, but at the same time ensure questions are marked as answered. Very good advice.

Answer (score 6):

You should make (if you can) a community wiki post:

[image]

In it, have this:

---

Answered by [XYZ](http://linktoxyzsprofile) *link to profile) in [comments](http://linktocomment) (link to comment):

> Comment content goes here, to explain the answer.

My pronouns are He / Him